# Will Distributed file system on 2 FTP servers work in two different data centers?

Tags: azure, ftp, vpn, microsoft-distributed-file-system, vnet

Currently we have 2 VMs in a VNet , both have FTP and DFS roles installed on them , also DFS replication is enabled.

1. The main question is that , if we have the above VMs in two different VNets (in different locations), will it allow me for Distributed file system(DFS) replication?
2. If not, will creating a VPN between those two VNets allow for DFS replication to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is not about DFS, rather about connectivity. Cross region VNets are not supported yet.
2. Yes, you would want to create a site-to-site VPN and forward traffic through that.

Comment: Thanks, will create a VPN between the Vnets and try the DFS replication through it.

Comment: no problem, if this answers your question - you should mark it as answer ;)